# Removing "Related Posts" when WooCommerce short code is posted on posts/pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, product

On my woocommerce web site, I use this code to remove titles from pages and post that displays products with a shortcode like **`[product_page id="99"]`**…

Here is that code:

```
function remove_some_product_titles(){
    if( !is_product() ){
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5);
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'remove_some_product_titles', 4);
```

How do you disable "Related Posts" when posting a WooCommerce shortcode to a post or page?

The Shortcode I use for WooCommerce is: **`[product_page id="99"]`**

Thanks

Comment: This question is does not fit http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Please edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This "Related Posts" are hooked in **`content_single-product.php`** WooCommerce template file as you can see below:

```
    /**
     * woocommerce_after_single_product_summary hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_upsell_display - 15
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_related_products - 20
     */
```

To remove  "Related Posts" only from your blog posts and pages, when outputted from a shortcode, you will need to add a condition like in my other answer. I will use that code to expand it for this purpose

Here is that functional and tested code:

```
function remove_some_product_titles(){
    if( !is_product() ){
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5);
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20);
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'remove_some_product_titles', 4);
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*

Comment: Perhaps due to changes in WooCommerce or WordPress in the time since you posted this answer, the `if ( !is_product() )` conditional no longer has the desired result. I'd like to implement some changes to product display -- as you said -- only "when outputted from a shortcode" on a post or page, but `is_product()` returns true in the case of the shortcode output just as on the WooCommerce product page. Do you happen to know how to test this condition in the current versions of WP/WooCommerce? My searches have proven fruitless so far. Thanks!

Comment: Alternately, could you perhaps suggest alternate ways to embed product info on another page of the site -- instead of the [product_page] shortcode? Do you think I'd better off writing my own custom shortcode?